# jQuery Autocomplete Plugin to jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a simple wikipedia autocomplete using the wikipedia's API.

Currently it is working using the jQuery autocomplete **Plugin** and I want to make it using jQuery UI.

Can someone guide me through please?

Here is the fiddle of a working demo using the plugin:
http://jsfiddle.net/VjLnv/

And here is the JS:

```
function attachWikiAutoComplete(expression) {
    $("#artist").autocomplete("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",  {
        dataType: "jsonp", 
        parse: function(data) { 
            var rows = new Array(); 
            var matches = data[1];
            for( var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){ 
                rows[i] = { data:matches[i], value:matches[i], result:matches[i] }; 
            } 
            return rows;
        },
        formatItem: function(row) { return row; }, 
        extraParams: {
            action: "opensearch", 
            format: "json", 
            search: function () { return $("#artist").val() } }, 
        max: 10 
    });
}
```

Thanks alot

Comment: I am using jQuery autocomplete Plugin instead of the default autocomplete which comes with jQuery ui and I want to change this so I won't be using that plugin. If you check the fiddle, try to remove the jquery.autocomplete.pack.js. It won't work anymore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the equivalent code in jQueryUI autocomplete:

```
$("#artist").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                'action': "opensearch",
                'format': "json",
                'search': request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data[1]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UGYzW/2/

Comment: Ey man literally I was wishing you would join my question. Haha, you done it again. You're inspiring me. What you know, its what I what I'm trying to learn